# GDI+ issue in uploading photos using asp.net with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, gdi+, image-uploading

I'm using the following code to resize and upload images to my server:

```
   Bitmap originalBMP = new Bitmap(uploader.FileContent);

   int origWidth = originalBMP.Width;
   int origHeight = originalBMP.Height;
   double sngRatio = (double)origWidth / origHeight;
   int newHeight = (int)Math.Ceiling(newWidth / sngRatio);

   Bitmap newBMP = new Bitmap(originalBMP, newWidth, newHeight);
   Graphics oGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(newBMP);

   oGraphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
   oGraphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
   oGraphics.DrawImage(originalBMP, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

   string uploadingMapPath = Path.Combine(serverMapPath, imageNewLocation);
   newBMP.Save(uploadingMapPath);

   originalBMP.Dispose();
   newBMP.Dispose();
   oGraphics.Dispose();
```

It works just fine in most of my projects, however, recently I've tried to use it again but this time it's not working and it keeps giving me "a generic error occurred in gdi+", I realized that when I provide the function with full path like in:`"C:/Users/Saajid-PC/Desktop/NewProject/MAXimages/upload"` the function will work just as I expected, but if I send this path: `"~/MAXimages"` the error will be generated ...
the saving part of this code is where this error being issued

> newBMP.Save(uploadingMapPath);

Any advice will be appreciated !

Comment: You really should use `using` statements instead of explicitly calling `.Dispose()` so dispose still gets called in the event of a exception.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Server.MapPath` on a location relative to the site (like ~/MAXimages) because the GDI+ method is expecting a full UNC or drive-mapped path like c:\folder\subfolder ..